# Unable to run Proj 'C' example

Tags: coordinate-system, proj

I use Proj 6.3 and I try to run Proj 'C' example from [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/blob/6.3/examples/pj_obs_api_mini_demo.c). I tried it using Qt 5.14.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. I created a 'C' project from Qt Creator and tried the example. I get the errors:

```
g++  -o proj_c main.o      
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
/home/edip/workspace/proj_c/main.c:42: undefined reference to `proj_context_create'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/workspace/proj_c/main.c:44: undefined reference to `proj_create_crs_to_crs'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/workspace/proj_c/main.c:57: undefined reference to `proj_normalize_for_visualization'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/workspace/proj_c/main.c:62: undefined reference to `proj_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/workspace/proj_c/main.c:68: undefined reference to `proj_coord'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/workspace//proj_c/main.c:71: undefined reference to `proj_trans'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/workspace/proj_c/main.c:73: undefined reference to `proj_trans'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/workspace/proj_c/main.c:77: undefined reference to `proj_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/workspace/proj_c/main.c:78: undefined reference to `proj_context_destroy'
```

Comment: If you don't include the library in the linker args, the linker can't resolve the library references.

Comment: I will try to add the include path in qmake. Thanks.

Comment: LIBPATH, I expect, unless it's LIB64PATH (-L flag)

Comment: I am sorry, I have only basic experience with c++ and I use it only on Qt Creator. I created new c project, I use qmake. using LIBPATH = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so gave error.

Comment: Actually I installed Proj library with package manager of Ubuntu. #include <proj.h> is detected automatically by the editor. I thought it will recognize all library paths and headers.

Comment: qnake pro file is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/w4q4yH6hfW/) .