# Undefined reference to `proj_context_create' while run PROJ example

Tags: proj, c++

I have installed Proj 6.3.1 and I tried to run a Proj example from https://proj.org/development/quickstart.html. I implemented it with CLion on Ubuntu 20.04. And I got many undefined reference errors as follows,

```
 cd "/path_to_the_file/" && g++ transformation.cpp -o transformation && "/path_to_the_file/"transformation
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cckO2X58.o: in function `main':
transformation.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `proj_context_create'
/usr/bin/ld: transformation.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `proj_create_crs_to_crs'
/usr/bin/ld: transformation.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `proj_normalize_for_visualization'
/usr/bin/ld: transformation.cpp:(.text+0xcb): undefined reference to `proj_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: transformation.cpp:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to `proj_coord'
/usr/bin/ld: transformation.cpp:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `proj_trans'
/usr/bin/ld: transformation.cpp:(.text+0x1c3): undefined reference to `proj_trans'
/usr/bin/ld: transformation.cpp:(.text+0x21c): undefined reference to `proj_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: transformation.cpp:(.text+0x228): undefined reference to `proj_context_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This problem is similar to [Unable to run Proj 'C' example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370771/unable-to-run-proj-c-example), but I can't find the solutions accordingly. The <proj.h> header is in my usr/include folder and Clion can detect it automatically.
Could anyone help?

Comment: This looks like a basic development issue of failing to include the library path and libraries in the compilation command.  [so] would be a much more useful resource for this.

Comment: try addig add -lproj after transformation.cpp  and before -o

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! But how can I change my code or CMake file so that I can run my code directly, not change the g++ command line manually?